# Deserialize Object using JDBC stored w/ JPA

Tags: java, serialization, jpa, jdbc, deserialization

I have a class which serializes an Image, and stores & retrieves it from a database using JPA.

I've decided to use Base64 instead of a serialization to ease up the process for other developers, so I am implementing at the startup of my application a which using JDBC:

- Reads the table searching for the serialized images.
- Deserializes the image.
- Stores in a different table the image as a Base64 image.
- Drops the tables and columns using the old serialized image.

The only problem is that when I deserialize the Image with the following code:

```
byte[] buf = rs.getBytes(tableImageField);
InputStream is = rs.getBlob(tableImageField).getBynaryStream();
ObjectInputStream oip = new ObjectInputStream(is);
ImageSerializer imageRead = (ImageSerializer) oip.readObject();
oip.close();
is.close();
rs.close();
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected block data
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1360)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1963)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1887)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1770)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1346)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:368)
at es.giro.girlabel.model.manager.AbstractManager.moveImageToCache(AbstractManager.java:199)
at es.giro.girlabel.model.manager.AbstractManager.upgradeDatabase(AbstractManager.java:158)
```

The serialized String looks like:

aced00057372002c65732e6769726f2e6769726c  ..... .....  .... .... ... b00000000049454e44ae42608278

As James has commented, I have tried to convert the serialized String (using an Hexadecimal format) to a byte array using this approach:

http://bit.ly/bncfKB

And got the exception:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected block data
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1360)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1963)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1887)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1770)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1346)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:368)
at es.giro.girlabel.model.manager.AbstractManager.moveImageToCache(AbstractManager.java:238)
at es.giro.girlabel.model.manager.AbstractManager.upgradeDatabase(AbstractManager.java:202)
```

Comment: Persisted using which JPA implementation, using which field mapping ?

Comment: Using eclipselink, in a @OneToOne field mapping.

Comment: Why do people keep saving media in a database? Ugh!

Answer (score 0):

The string looks like hex, not a binary string, you probably need to convert it from hex to binary first.

How did you store the data?  What is the database type?

Comment: The database type is a String. I'll try to convert it to bynary, and post the results...

Comment: I have tried using this hex to byte array converter: http://bit.ly/bncfKB     java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected block data
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1360)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1963)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1887)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1770)